# Why am I getting index out of bounds error from database

Tags: c#, database, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I know what index out of bounds is all about. When I debug I see why as well. basically what is happening is I do a filter on my database to look for records that are potential/pending. I then gather a array of those numbers send them off to another server to check to see if those numbers have been upgraded to a sale. If it has been upgraded to a sale the server responds back with the new Sales Order ID and my old Pending Sales Order ID (SourceID). I then do a for loop on that list to filter it down that specific SourceID and update the SourceID to be the Sales Order ID and change a couple of other values. Problem is is that when I use that filter on the very first one it throws a index out of bounds error. I check the results returned by the filter and it says 0. Which i find kind of strange because I took the sales order number from the list so it should be there. So i dont know what the deal is. Here is the code in question that throws the error. And it doesn't do it all the time. Like I just ran the code this morning and it didn't throw the error. But last night it did before I went home.

```
        filter.RowFilter = string.Format("Stage = '{0}'", Potential.PotentialSale);
        if (filter.Count > 0)
        {
            var Soids = new int[filter.Count];
            Console.Write("Searching for Soids - (");
            for (int i = 0; i < filter.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(filter[i][1].ToString() + ",");
                Soids[i] = (int)filter[i][1];
            }
            Console.WriteLine(")");
            var pendingRecords = Server.GetSoldRecords(Soids);
            var updateRecords = new NameValueCollection();
            for (int i = 0; i < pendingRecords.Length; i++)
            {
                filter.RowFilter = "Soid = " + pendingRecords[i][1];
                filter[0].Row["Soid"] = pendingRecords[i][0];
                filter[0].Row["SourceId"] = pendingRecords[i][1];
                filter[0].Row["Stage"] = Potential.ClosedWon;
                var potentialXML = Potential.GetUpdatePotentialXML(filter[0].Row["Soid"].ToString(), filter[0].Row["Stage"].ToString());
                updateRecords.Add(filter[0].Row["ZohoID"].ToString(), potentialXML);
            }
```

if i'm counting right line 17 is the error where the error is thrown. pendingRecords is a object[][] array. pendingRecords[i] is the individual records. pendingRecords[i][0] is the new Sales OrderID (SOID) and pendingRecords[i][1] is the old SOID (now the SourceID)

Any help on this one? is it because i'm changing the SOID to the new SOID, and the filter auto updates itself? I just don't know

Comment: You have three indexes on that line: one in `filter[0]` and two in `pendingRecords[i][0]`.  If `pendingRecords[i]` didn't fail in the previous line, it shouldn't fail in line 17.  Similarly, `pendingRecords[i]` must have the same number of elements in line 17 as in 16, so `pendingRecords[1][0]` must succeed.  You just set the filter's `RowFilter` property in the previous line.  I wonder whether that doesn't change the filter's `Count` to zero.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying. The results returned in this instance was pendingRecords[0] = {4462, 20496} which was the only record return. Last night pendingRecords had 13 records. They will always have matching records because of my Server.GetSoldRecords call. I was under the assumption that RowFilter was a Get;Set; method that wasn't a list but rather just a string. So i don't get why it's not filtering correctly. Last night the filter read "Soid = 20424" and filter.Count = 0. Which is strange because when i opened my database SOID 20424 is there. So i dunno.

Comment: What type is `filter`?  What does the documentation of its `RowFilter` property say?

Comment: var filter = AllPotentials.Table.DefaultView;Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the expression used to filter which rows are viewed in the System.Data.DataView.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A string that specifies how rows are to be filtered. For more information,
        //     see the Remarks section.

Comment: I find it strange too that sometimes when an exception is thrown it doesn't show up in my exceptions nor does it stop the program. Which i'm used to errors when they are thrown and not caught that it crashes the program. Working with databases has to be the hardest thing i've done lately when it comes to programming. Like for instance after it finds these records it was supposed to update them on a website, and I have code that says "sending to zoho" but it never was called. I also have a timer for every hour and that event was never triggered. Strange strange.

Comment: The documentation for DataTable.DefaultView and DataView.RowFilter don't seem to help much.  At this point, all I can think to recommend is that you step through the code in the debugger, and check that local variables hold the expected values; I'd start with `pendingRecords` and with examining `filter` both before and after you set its `RowFilter` property.  Also, how do you know an exception is being thrown if it doesn't show up in exceptions and doesn't crash the program?

Comment: well I maybe don't KNOW but before I made my TableAdapter from scratch I had similar problems when I was using the autogenerated one. It would say it had a concurrent violation (sometimes) and not execute anymore code. The times it didn't throw a error message it still wouldn't proceed after my update method. I was able to narrow it down by putting in some Console.WriteLine statments in and noticed that it wouldn't call ones after my update call. So then i would comment it out and the rest of my code would run just fine. Similar thing is happening here in that it isn't throwing a error.

Comment: -continue- but it also isn't executing the rest of the code after my update again. Which leads me to believe it is throwing an exception but it, for some strange reason, isn't raising the event of an exception being thrown. As for stepping through the program it my array of Soid has expected values. my server is also returning the expected values. The filter seems to be my weakest link and I can't find out why. Also i have a hard time navigating through the Watcher for my DataView. (as in i can't find the rows of values) just the RowFilter and the Count are easy to find.

Comment: I figured it out. I have to wait 6 more hours before i can post the answer. basically i had to change my filter to string.Format("Soid = '{0}'", pendingProducts[i][1]);

Comment: @RobertSnyder You should post you answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I ended up changing how it worked all together and it actually sorts it a bit nicer now. The code i am about to post has a bunch of hard coded numbers due to the structure of my table that is returned. Sorry about that. I have learned since then to not do that, but i am working on a different project now and will change that when I have to change the program. But here is the solution.

```
        var potentials = Server.GetNewPotentials(); //loads all records from server
        for (int i = 0; i < potentials.Length; i++)
        {
            var filter = AllPotentials.DefaultView;
            var result1 = CheckSoidOrSource(potentials[i].Soid, true);
            var result2 = CheckSoidOrSource(potentials[i].SourceID,false) ;
            //This potential can't be found at all so let's add it to our table
            if (result1+result2==0)
            {
                Logger.WriteLine("Found new record. Adding it to DataTable and sending it to Zoho");
                AllPotentials.Add(potentials[i]);
                filter.RowFilter = string.Format("Soid = '{0}'", potentials[i].SourceID);
                var index = AllPotentials.Rows.IndexOf(filter[0].Row);
                ZohoPoster posterInsert = new ZohoPoster(Zoho.Fields.Potentials, Zoho.Calls.insertRecords);
                AllPotentials.Rows[index]["ZohoID"] = posterInsert.PostNewPotentialRecord(3, filter[0].Row);
            }
            //This potential is not found, but has a SourceId that matches a Soid of another record.
            if (result1==0 && result2 == 1)
            {
                Logger.WriteLine("Found a record that needs to be updated on Zoho");
                ZohoPoster posterUpdate = new ZohoPoster(Zoho.Fields.Potentials, Zoho.Calls.updateRecords);

                filter.RowFilter = string.Format("Soid = '{0}'", potentials[i].SourceID);
                var index = AllPotentials.Rows.IndexOf(filter[0].Row);
                AllPotentials.Rows[index]["Soid"] = potentials[i].Soid;
                AllPotentials.Rows[index]["SourceId"] = potentials[i].SourceID;
                AllPotentials.Rows[index]["PotentialStage"] = potentials[i].PotentialStage;
                AllPotentials.Rows[index]["UpdateRecord"] = true;
                AllPotentials.Rows[index]["Amount"] = potentials[i].Amount;
                AllPotentials.Rows[index]["ZohoID"] = posterUpdate.UpdatePotentialRecord(3, filter[0].Row);
            }
        }
        AllPotentials.AcceptChanges();
    }
    private int CheckSoidOrSource(string Soid, bool checkSource)
    {
        var filter = AllPotentials.DefaultView;
        if (checkSource)
            filter.RowFilter = string.Format("Soid = '{0}' OR SourceId = '{1}'",Soid, Soid);
        else
            filter.RowFilter = string.Format("Soid = '{0}'", Soid);

        return filter.Count;
    }
```

basically what is happening is that i noticed something about my data when I filter it this way. The two results would only return the following results (0,0) (0,1) and (1,0) (0,0) means that the record doesn't exist at all in this table so I need to add it. (1,0) means that the Sales Order ID (Soid) matches another Soid in the table so it already exists. Lastly (0,1) means that the Soid doesn't exist in this table but i found a record that has the Soid as it's source...which to me means that the one that had it as a source has been upgraded from a potential to a sale, which in turn means i have to update the record and Zoho.  This worked out to much less work for me because now I don't have to search for won and lost records, i only have to search for lost records. less code same results is always a good thing :)